# Error when building ros packages on MAC OS X Yosemite

Tags: catkin, cmake, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to install ROS-indigo on Mac OS X Yosemite but i will be damned soon :) . I created a workspace and following code worked properly.

```
$ rosinstall_generator desktop_full --rosdistro indigo --deps --wet-only --tar > indigo-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall
$ wstool init -j8 src indigo-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall
```

but;

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
```

this code produces an error:

```
executing command [brew install opencv]
Warning: opencv-2.4.10.1 already installed, it's just not linked
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  homebrew: Failed to detect successful installation of [opencv]
```

I skip this error and I tried to build src files by using:

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

The problem is: First 8 packaged built completely but 9. package  ( class_loader ) produce error:

```
-- catkin 0.6.11
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findconsole_bridge.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "console_bridge", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "console_bridge"
  with any of the following names:

    console_bridgeConfig.cmake
    console_bridge-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "console_bridge" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "console_bridge_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "console_bridge" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "/Users/Hakan/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/class_loader/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    <== Failed to process package 'class_loader': 
      Command '/Users/Hakan/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /Users/Hakan/ros_catkin_ws/src/class_loader -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/Hakan/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/class_loader -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/Hakan/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G Unix Makefiles' returned non-zero exit status 1
    
    Reproduce this error by running:
    ==> cd /Users/Hakan/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/class_loader && /Users/Hakan/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /Users/Hakan/ros_catkin_ws/src/class_loader -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/Hakan/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/class_loader -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/Hakan/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G Unix Makefiles
    
    Command failed, exiting.
```

I googling for a long time but i couldn't find any solution.

any suggestion ??

Thanks...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204361/error-when-building-ros-packages-on-mac-os-x-yosemite/) by [heyikan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21786/heyikan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-03-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I skip this error and I tried to build src files by using:

You need to continue past that error. Use something like:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y --skip-keys libopencv-dev
```

To skip the check on opencv, but continue installing other dependencies.

Or you could actually resolve the issue with opencv, it pretty clearly states that you've installed opencv from Homebrew already but it has not been linked. (see: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#what-does-keg-only-mean)

The error about not finding `console_bridgeConfig.cmake` is because you didn't let `rosdep` install all of the dependencies (like `console_bridge`).

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1